# Laying out django-markdownx preview widget in a different place

Tags: django

I'm writing a simple notetaking app using Django, and I have come across [django-markdownx](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx). In short, it's great and it's exactly what I need, however I'm having an issue with laying out preview widget to be where I want. So, currently, the rendered text is displayed below my textarea, and I want them side by side. I found [this](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/customization/), but haven't successfully tailored it so it suits my needs. The widgets seem to be dependant upon each other, i.e. they have to go into the same template, and I would like to lay them out the way I want in my own template which looks roughly like this:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="form-header">
    Create a new note
  </div>
  [...]
  <form method="POST">
      [...]
  </form>
</div>
<div class="preview">
  <!-- Preview widget should go here -->
</div>
```

Can I somehow overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

paste these lines in your widget.html

```
    {% load i18n %}
<div class="d-block w-100">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="{{widget.name}}-write-tab" href="#{{widget.name}}-tab-write"
               data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="write" aria-selected="true">
                {% trans "Write" %}
            </a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="{{widget.name}}-preview-tab" href="#{{widget.name}}-tab-preview"
               data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="preview" aria-selected="true">
                {% trans "Preview" %}
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="markdownx tab-content" id="{{widget.name}}-tabs">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="{{widget.name}}-tab-write" role="tabpanel"
             aria-labelledby="{{widget.name}}-tab-write">
            {% include 'django/forms/widgets/textarea.html' %}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{widget.name}}-tab-preview" role="tabpanel"
             aria-labelledby="{{widget.name}}-tab-preview">
            <div class="markdownx-preview"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```